# Repeat a javascript code with a different number in each run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I don't know the terminology but hoping this explanation makes sense. I have a JavaScript code that I want to repeat 10 times, each time with an increasing number to target each td in a table (first td then the second then the third and so on)

The goal of this JavaScript is to match the TD width of the thead to the one in the tbody (this is because I have them separated via css with position:absolute).

Right now I managed to match the width of a single TD with this:

```
var cell4 = $('#divResults tbody > td:nth-child(4)');
$('#divResults thead > tr > td:nth-child(4)').css({ width: cell4.width()});
```

The easiest, but not practical, way to accomplish setting the remaining TDs is to duplicate the JS but replacing the numbers 9 more times.

I know there is a way to create a loop and target each TD without manual duplication of the code but can't seem to find an answer online.

I appreciate the help

Comment: What you're looking for is a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: I appreciate all the comments and tried applying each one to see what works best

Should've clarified even more, each td in the tbody has a different width, so I want to match each td with their respective widths. Hence my need to make thead td1 match with tbody td1 and tbody td2 match with thead td2 and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting a specific element, select all elements and loop over them.

```
$('#divResults tbody > td').each(function( index ) {
  // Do some repeating code
});
```

Link for more details
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla JS you would use a for loop to achieve this. Using jQuery you can just grab a collection of `<td>`s and loop over them using `.each`

```
// Get the first tr's collection of td elements
var bodyTds = $('#divResults tbody tr:first-child td');

// Loop over the head td's (should be th's really)
$('#divResults thead tr td').each(function(index) {
    // Apply the width of the body td to the head td
    $(this).css({ width: bodyTds.eq(index).width()});
});
```

Comment: I believe OP wants `head.eq(index).css(...)` " to match the TD width of the thead to the one in the tbody"

Comment: Woops, you're right... that's actually why I put the first-child in but didn't switch the tbody and thead. Thanks for the spot.